# Rails cart won't update on second addition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a shopping cart, an item can be added and the cart will be displayed showing the item in the cart with quantity one, when I add the same item to the cart it is added but the cart does not get updated until I add the item again or the same item, or refresh the cart.
Adding a third item of the same will update the cart and show the correct quantity, it just doesn't update after adding the second same item, and will show the quantity as one less until the page gets refreshed or until a different is added to the cart!

The code is mostly from the book 'agile web dev with rails' 3.2 version.

```
line_items/create.js.erb
if ($('#cart tr').length > 0) { $('#cart').show(); }
$('#cart').html("<%=j render @cart %>");



class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
      def create
        @cart = current_cart
        item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
          @line_item = @cart.add_item(item.id)
          respond_to do |format|
            if @line_item.save
              puts @cart
              format.js { @current_item = @line_item}
              format.html { redirect_to store_url,
                notice: "#{item.name} added to cart." }
              format.json { render json: @line_item,
                status: :created, location: @line_item }
            else
              format.html { render action: "new" }
              format.json { render json: @line_item.errors,
                status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
      end

    end

carts/show.html.haml
= render @cart

carts/_cart.html.haml
= render cart.line_items



line_items/_line_item.html.erb

   <% if line_item == @current_item %>
<tr id="current_item">
<% else %>
<tr>
<% end %>
<td><%= line_item.quantity %> &times;</td>
<td><%= line_item.item.name %></td>
<td class="item_price"><%= number_to_pounds(line_item.total_price) %></td>
</tr>




class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  def add_item(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_item_id(product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(item_id: product_id)
    end
    current_item
  end
```

Comment: What does @cart.add_item do?

Comment: It's a method on the cart model

Comment: @raphael_turtle, what is #cart tr?

Comment: it checks if anything is displayed in the cart

Comment: Could you post the code for that method?

Comment: add_item is not changing the object its called on (@cart). You will have to do `@cart << line_item` after you line_item is saved

Comment: calling @cart = current_cart after line_item is saved fixes it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the @cart object was always a step behind as it wasn't updated after saving.
setting `@cart = current_cart` after saving in the line_items controller works, as does using
`@cart.reload` when rendering the cart view instead.